# Object complex transformation

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to find a good utility (*Lodash* or some other) to help with transforming fairly deeply nested objects like this:

## Source Data:

```
  [{
  "category": "blogs",
  "results": {
      "__type": "SearchProvider.SearchResultContainer",
      "SearchResults": [{
          "SearchId": null,
          "MetaData": [{
              "Name": "id",
              "Value": "618",
              "Other": "",
              "Count": 0,
              "Checked": true
          }, {
              "Name": "PostID",
              "Value": "618",
              "Other": "",
              "Count": 0,
              "Checked": true
          }, {
              "Name": "PublishDate",
              "Value": "10/08/2012 6:28:00 AM",
              "Other": "",
              "Count": 0,
              "Checked": true
          }, {
              "Name": "_version_",
              "Value": 1571711408793452500,
              "Other": "",
              "Count": 0,
              "Checked": true
          }]
      }, {
          "SearchId": null,
          "MetaData": [{
              "Name": "id",
              "Value": "605",
              "Other": "",
              "Count": 0,
              "Checked": true
          }, {
              "Name": "PostID",
              "Value": "605",
              "Other": "",
              "Count": 0,
              "Checked": true
          }, {
              "Name": "PublishDate",
              "Value": "03/01/2011 8:16:00 PM",
              "Other": "",
              "Count": 0,
              "Checked": true
          }, {
              "Name": "_version_",
              "Value": 1571711408284893200,
              "Other": "",
              "Count": 0,
              "Checked": true
          }]
      }]
  }
}]
```

And produce this result to get the property name `id` and `PublishDate` and their values from the `MetaData` array in each `SearchResults` object:

## Expected Data:

```
[
    {
        "id": "618",
        "PublishDate": "10/08/2012 6:28:00 AM"
    },
    {
        "id": "605",
        "PublishDate": "03/01/2011 8:16:00 PM"
    }
]
```

I've tried using [json-query](https://github.com/mmckegg/json-query) and find the syntax to be easy to grok, especially with the online testing tool (https://maxleiko.github.io/json-query-tester/), but couldn't produce this result.

This question was marked as "on hold" saying that it doesn't meet guidelines because its asking for a "recommendation" and not an explicit solution. While I understand the arbitrariness of asking for recommendations and getting a subjective list of responses, the sense in which I'm asking for a recommendation here is not in this manner. I was asking for feedback from experienced JS developers and different patterns (either built-in ES6 objects or other utility libraries, e.g. Lodash) *how they would get this result (objectively)*. So in this sense, there is an objective question and answer being asked for. But I understand that since there are different ways to get this result, then a single answer is not easily identified. I believe this speaks more to a limitation of the SO format (in this case) where a question becomes "off topic". If there is another place to post this kind of best-practice approaches that is better suited to a variety of good responses (like both the responses the question has received), then I would gladly post there. In any event, both of the answers provided to this question have helped me understand how this can be solved via the two different methods. The ES6 answer has helped me to understand how leverage built-in ES6 features (destructing and spread operator) to get the result. And the Lodash answer has helped me to understand how this can be done with it. Thank you to both who have provided answers - I wish I could select both your answers for recognition (which, I understand is why this question is flagged as not meeting SO guidelines).

Since I did state that I would like to use a "utility" like Lodash, I will select the Lodash answer (even though the ES6 answer has helped me to better use its built in features).

Comment: your question was almost closed. I've managed to save it from it by editing it and also removing any requested for recommendations. asking for such things is not allowed on *stackoverflow* so be aware in your next question never to ask for any recommendation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Using [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#find) this can be done quite easily:

```js
var data = [{
  "category": "blogs",
  "results": {
      "__type": "SearchProvider.SearchResultContainer",
      "SearchResults": [{
          "SearchId": null,
          "MetaData": [{
              "Name": "id",
              "Value": "618",
              "Other": "",
              "Count": 0,
              "Checked": true
          }, {
              "Name": "PostID",
              "Value": "618",
              "Other": "",
              "Count": 0,
              "Checked": true
          }, {
              "Name": "PublishDate",
              "Value": "10/08/2012 6:28:00 AM",
              "Other": "",
              "Count": 0,
              "Checked": true
          }, {
              "Name": "_version_",
              "Value": 1571711408793452500,
              "Other": "",
              "Count": 0,
              "Checked": true
          }]
      }, {
          "SearchId": null,
          "MetaData": [{
              "Name": "id",
              "Value": "605",
              "Other": "",
              "Count": 0,
              "Checked": true
          }, {
              "Name": "PostID",
              "Value": "605",
              "Other": "",
              "Count": 0,
              "Checked": true
          }, {
              "Name": "PublishDate",
              "Value": "03/01/2011 8:16:00 PM",
              "Other": "",
              "Count": 0,
              "Checked": true
          }, {
              "Name": "_version_",
              "Value": 1571711408284893200,
              "Other": "",
              "Count": 0,
              "Checked": true
          }]
      }]
  }
}];

// transformation:
var newData = data[0].results.SearchResults.map(d => {
  return {
    id          : _.find(d.MetaData, {"Name":"id"}).Value,
    PublishDate : _.find(d.MetaData, {"Name":"PublishDate"}).Value
  }
})
    
    
console.log( newData )
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

## With ES2015 `find` method:

```js
var data = [{
  "category": "blogs",
  "results": {
      "__type": "SearchProvider.SearchResultContainer",
      "SearchResults": [{
          "SearchId": null,
          "MetaData": [{
              "Name": "id",
              "Value": "618",
              "Other": "",
              "Count": 0,
              "Checked": true
          }, {
              "Name": "PostID",
              "Value": "618",
              "Other": "",
              "Count": 0,
              "Checked": true
          }, {
              "Name": "PublishDate",
              "Value": "10/08/2012 6:28:00 AM",
              "Other": "",
              "Count": 0,
              "Checked": true
          }, {
              "Name": "_version_",
              "Value": 1571711408793452500,
              "Other": "",
              "Count": 0,
              "Checked": true
          }]
      }, {
          "SearchId": null,
          "MetaData": [{
              "Name": "id",
              "Value": "605",
              "Other": "",
              "Count": 0,
              "Checked": true
          }, {
              "Name": "PostID",
              "Value": "605",
              "Other": "",
              "Count": 0,
              "Checked": true
          }, {
              "Name": "PublishDate",
              "Value": "03/01/2011 8:16:00 PM",
              "Other": "",
              "Count": 0,
              "Checked": true
          }, {
              "Name": "_version_",
              "Value": 1571711408284893200,
              "Other": "",
              "Count": 0,
              "Checked": true
          }]
      }]
  }
}];


var newData = data[0].results.SearchResults.map(d => {
  return {
    id          : d.MetaData.find(item => item.Name == 'id').Value,
    PublishDate : d.MetaData.find(item => item.Name == 'PublishDate').Value
  }
}) 

console.log(newData)
```

### Protection against possible missing keys

If, for example, one of the `find` method doesn't match for anything, it will return `undefined` and `undefined` doesn't have the `.value` key since it's not an object:

#### Fix:

```
var newData = data[0].results.SearchResults.map(d => {
  return {
    id : (d.MetaData.find(item => item.Name == 'XXX')||{}).Value, // no match for "find" (undefined)
    PublishDate : (d.MetaData.find(item => item.Name == 'PublishDate')||{}).Value
  }
})
```

Because:

```js
var a = [{foo:1}];

console.log( a.find(v => v).foo )        // = 1
console.log( (a.find(v => !v)||{}).foo ) // = undefined
console.log( a.find(v => !v).foo )       // ERROR
```

Comment: What does Lodash give me here that I can't get with ES6 find? 
var newData = data[0].results.SearchResults.map(d => {
  return {
    id: d.MetaData.find(meta => meta.Name === 'id').Value,
    pubDate: d.MetaData.find(meta => meta.Name === 'PublishDate').Value,
  }
})

Comment: it's a collection of already-made functions so your own code can be shorter and is more readable. I prefer using that than writing thing like that every time I need some data transformation (and I do need it **a lot**). it's much easier to maintain for other team members which aren't in a very high coding level and have difficulties understanding complex ES6 code. Don't you think it's much more readable and elegant?

Comment: I agree that Lodash provides many utility functions that make they syntax shorter and, in this way, easier to understand. I was referring specifically to the .find method, and that I don't see a difference between using the ES6 built-in find and the Lodash find, in my example here. But between your transformation code, and Ori's below, your's is much easier for me to digest, as Ori's uses destructuring, concat, and spread operators in conjunction with map and find (both of which you use). Thanks!

Comment: You can use ES6 `find` method also. I will update my answer

Answer (score 2):

Javascript has all tools needed to parse this structure, and using ES6 arrow functions, and destructuring make it even easier:

```js
const data = [{"category":"blogs","results":{"__type":"SearchProvider.SearchResultContainer","SearchResults":[{"SearchId":null,"MetaData":[{"Name":"id","Value":"618","Other":"","Count":0,"Checked":true},{"Name":"PostID","Value":"618","Other":"","Count":0,"Checked":true},{"Name":"PublishDate","Value":"10/08/2012 6:28:00 AM","Other":"","Count":0,"Checked":true},{"Name":"_version_","Value":1571711408793452500,"Other":"","Count":0,"Checked":true}]},{"SearchId":null,"MetaData":[{"Name":"id","Value":"605","Other":"","Count":0,"Checked":true},{"Name":"PostID","Value":"605","Other":"","Count":0,"Checked":true},{"Name":"PublishDate","Value":"03/01/2011 8:16:00 PM","Other":"","Count":0,"Checked":true},{"Name":"_version_","Value":1571711408284893200,"Other":"","Count":0,"Checked":true}]}]}}];

const getValueFromMeta = (meta, name) => (meta.find(({ Name }) => Name === name) || {}).Value; // get a value from  metadata according to name

/** if the metadata structure is consistent you can use this instead
const propToIndex = { id: 0, PublishDate: 2 };
const getValueFromMeta = (meta, name) => (meta[propToIndex[name]] || {}).Value;
 **/

const result = [].concat( // flatten the arrays
  ...data.map(({ results }) => // map the data
    results.SearchResults.map(({ MetaData }) => ({ // map the search results, and create object
      id: getValueFromMeta(MetaData, 'id'), // get the value for id
      PublishDate: getValueFromMeta(MetaData, 'PublishDate') // get the value for publish date
  })))
);

console.log(result);
```